# dpkg returning errors during apt-get upgrade s

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I run  sudo apt-get upgrade and at the end these errors are encountered

```
(Reading database ... 1234017 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-doc_4%3a5.3.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
install-info: No dir file specified; try --help for more information.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-doc_4%3a5.3.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 there is no script in the new version of the package - giving up
install-info: No dir file specified; try --help for more information.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-doc_4%3a5.3.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What do ` sudo install-info --version` and `sudo which install-info` print?

Comment: install-info (GNU texinfo) 6.1

Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: sudo which install-info
/usr/bin/install-info